# TypeScript associative array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

So I'm trying to `group` some reservations `by business id`. I'm looking for an end result like this:

> [ [businessID1] => [Object1,Object2, Object3], [businessID2] => [Object1,Object2],
>   [businessID3] => [Object1,Object2] ]

My current code:

```
let groups = new Array;
this.reservations.map(function (value) {
  groups[value.businessID] = value;
});
```

So right now it doesn't work... because each time it's going to re-write that array key. I'm new to the typescript/js world, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41554523/group-by-javascript-object-keys-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the value does not exist, create an empty array, and append the value to it with `push`:

```
if (groups[value.businessID] === undefined) {
  groups[value.businessID] = [];
}
groups[value.businessID].push(value);
```

Or more compactly:

```
(groups[value.businessID] = groups[value.businessID] || []).push(value);
```